# Grails - Login page with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, grails

I'd like to build my login page with AngularJS, but I have problem with displaying it.

This is my `web-app/apps/loginPage/app.js` for login page:

```
var app = angular.module('login-app', [
    'ngRoute'
]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'apps/loginPage/views/login.html'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
```

And this is my `grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp` code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name='layout' content='main'/>
    <script src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'jquery-1.9.1.js')}"></script>
    <script src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'angular.js')}" ></script>
    <script src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'angular-route.js')}"></script>
    <script src="${resource(dir: 'apps/loginPage', file: 'app.js')}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="login-app">
        <div ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/myApp/login/auth`, page loads angular app, but doesn't load login form from `login.html` file, because it tries to find it under `http://localhost:8080/myApp/login/apps/loginPage/views/login.html` instead of `http://localhost:8080/myApp/apps/loginPage/views/login.html`

How can I fix the path? How can I tell angular to use `localhost:8080/myApp` as a root for resources? 
(Note that i have *.gsp files in `grails-app/views` and angular app in `web-app/apps/`)

I don't know if it's problem with configuring Grails or Angular.

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you rephrase this as a general AngularJS + Grails question and not one that's specific to Spring Security. It has nothing to do with security, and you're excluding people who might help you but don't know Spring Security

Answer (score 1):

After experience with 3 projects in Grails & Angular, I recommend you to do the whole frontend part in pure Angular. I haven't even mixed GSP in Angular, rather used pure HTML with handlebars and localisation via angular-translate. Application login is implemented via Spring Security AJAX login.

If you completely separate the frontend from the backend, you can use for the frontend existing scaffolding tools like Yeoman or Brunch. Also delivering of HTML fragments can be cached, zipped etc.

Comment: I also think about it, but I heard that using static pages is better for search engines, and that's why I wanted to mix angular with gsp. For example I want to build my home page, faq, company info etc as static pages but user profile control panel, and every forms or list views with angular. Maybe I will change this conception. Thanks for tip about keeping spring security login page with pure ajax.

Comment: You're right, the search engines need ther "static" html. So you have 2 options, there's a plugin for Grails, which integrates your pallication with a service, which generates HTML output for the SPA aapplication. Or you split the application into public part with regular GSP rendering and a part behing security, which can be SPA. I've already created 2 such applications, works without a trouble :-)

Comment: @Tom please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152633/grai-as-single-app-or-different-back-end-and-front-end-app

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix templateUrl with "static/" or "/assets"(depends on grails version) while using angularjs with grails

Here is the url routing for angular views with grails app
https://github.com/mannejkumar/GrailsAngularDemoApp/blob/master/grails-app/assets/javascripts/app/app.js

**Demo** : http://jagadeesh-manne.rhcloud.com/

**Source** : http://mannejkumar.github.io/GrailsAngularDemoApp/